# JDBC call to a synonym to Microsoft SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

Using the JDBC driver provided by Microsoft (sqljdbc4.jar) I am unable to call a stored procedure using a synonym defined for it.
I.e. for a synonym defined as:

```
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.synonym_name for dbo.procedure_name
```

when running the callable statement created by:

```
CallableStatement callStmt = conn.prepareCall("{ call [dbo].[synonym_name] (?,?,?,?,?,?) }");
```

I get an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Parameter param_name was not defined for stored procedure [dbo].[synonym_name].
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:171)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerCallableStatement.findColumn(SQLServerCallableStatement.java:1217)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerCallableStatement.setString(SQLServerCallableStatement.java:1563)
    at testmssql.main(testmssql.java:53)
```

Even though the parameters are correctly set (if I call the procedure directly (bypassing the synonym) everything works fine).

Further more, if I replace Microsoft's driver with JTDS, everything works fine.

**How can one run a `CallableStatement` using a synonym for a stored procedure with Microsoft SQL Server's JDBC driver?**

Comment: I see that there's an issue, but what's the question?

Comment: @Paul Sasik - I've added a question - it's probably hard to read but I couldn't phrase it better.

Comment: +1 Sounds good. I assumed that was a solution you were looking for but there were several paths from your OP. Btw, why is JTDS not a good solution? And do you have to have a synonym for the stored proc?

Comment: @Paul Sasik - JTDS or not using the synonym are both valid options but I'm investigating why we get an exception with the MS driver. AFAIK the synonym is there to bridge an existing stored procedure into our project's namespace.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server Synonyms do not have query-able metadata. Judging by the error, JDBC is trying to confirm that the parameters declared in the Java code match the parameters declared on the stored procedure. That fails because of the missing metadata.

The only way around this is to create a passthrough stored procedure instead of the synonym.
So if you have this procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.RealProcedure
@p1 INT,
@p2 INT
AS
BEGIN
  RAISERROR('TODO: implement me',16,10);
END
```

And you have this synonym:

```
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.myProcedure FOR dbo.realProcedure;
```

Drop the synonym and create this procedure instead:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.myProcedure
@p1 INT,
@p2 INT
AS
BEGIN
  EXEC dbo.realProcedure @p1,@p2;
END
```

There is a similar issue described here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/sqldataaccess/thread/dcdfee17-a926-4b57-8641-ed86fec989f2